# How "cm find" works in plasticscm

Tags: plasticscm

I have created a workspace for a cloud repo and when run `cm find` if fetch data from cloud repo directly.so, i got these follow up question

1. How `cm find` work to communicate to cloud?
2. if it works like rest call, is there any rate limit ?

Answer (score 2):

It does work calling an API of the cloud server, there is no specific rate limit so for any number of integrations and automations you should not have any problem (If you are not **intentionally** generating **excessive** amounts of load, in that case you might get blocked).